# PostSharp Diagnostics Toolkit - Can the message format be changed?

Tags: .net, log4net, postsharp

I'm using the PostSharp Diagnostics Toolkit with Log4Net and it is working verynicely.  However, the output contains the namespace and class twice on each line.

Log4Net is configured to use a standard pattern layout

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
</layout>
```

This is producing the output:

```
2012-11-15 11:03:22,992 [ServerScheduler_Worker-3] DEBUG MyNamespace.MyClass - Entering: MyNamespace.MyClass.MyMethod(DateTime date = {11/15/2012 00:00:00})
```

Notice MyNamespace.MyClass is repeated.  I do want Log4Net to output the %logger (namespace and class) for log statements not injected by by PostSharp.

How can I configure PostSharp to only output the method name rather than the full namespace.classname.methodname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good point. It is not possible to customize it currently. I added a user story to our backlog.

Comment: Has this been implemented?

Comment: No, thjs has not been implemented and actually we are no longer considering implementing it, because we cannot see a strong use case.

Comment: @GaelFraiteur Please reconsider this. There are many use cases for wanting to have the message format changed before handing it off to a logging framework such as NLog. In my case, I don't want to have to force NLog to do a regex on the message that's passed to it. This seems to be a very key feature that's missing from this awesome tool.